# sql select expression order

Tags: sql, select, reporting-services

I have a huge db with hundreds of tables each with many columns. Trying to rewrite an `SQL` expression to help me figuring out how to change it according to user requests.
What I ran into is changing the order or selected columns breaks the expression, as in `ssrs` gives me various error messages.
Is it even possible that `SELECT t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3, t2.cc1, t3.ccc1 <something>` isn't equivalent to `SELECT t1.c1, t3.ccc1, t1.c3, t2.cc1, t1.c2 <same something>`?

Comment: That both the select clause you just mentioned are equivalent. Please elaborate your question, as what do you want to do, and what errors are occurring when you try to achieve that.

Comment: If you are talking about changing a dataset query and all you are doing is reordering columns then that should be fine. If the number of columns or names and/or datatypes change then that will not work as SSRS won't be able to map the column names.

Comment: Thank you turns out the problem is with ssrs and type casting (bigint/varchar/nvarchar) the same query which didn't work in ssrs 3.0 works in ssrs 4.0